# Redirect deleted images url to home page in .htaccess file

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have deleted some images from my website but for SEO purposes I want to redirect those image path(URL) to my homepage. I have put this code in my .htaccess file but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   # not a dir   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   # not a file
RewriteRule ^.*\.(.jpg|.jpeg|.png|.gif)$ https://www.homepage.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern has extra dots.

You may try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: will this redirect all deleted images URL to the homepage?

Comment: Yes it will as long as images extension is one of `jpg, jpeg, png, gif`

Comment: `not working` type of comment is of no use. What URL did you enter in browser? What error did you get? Are there more rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: If there are other rules then make sure this is topmost rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: one last question `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule . /index.php [L] </IfModule>` there's this code in my .htaccess file can I put this image redirection code in this after rewrite engine on?

Comment: Yes this suggested rule should be placed just below `RewriteBase /` line.